# Swift Camera Zooming

Tags: avfoundation, swift5, ios-camera, xcode11.4

I’m trying to zoom in if a button gets pressed.
Apple writes in its [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624611-videozoomfactor) that I have to call `lockForConfiguration()` and `unlockForConfiguration()` when im changing the `videoZoomFactor`’s value. But I’m unsure if this is the right way to implement.

```
@IBAction func zoomBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        do {
            try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        captureDevice.videoZoomFactor = 10

        do {
            try captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

For the `unlockForConfiguration()` I get two warnings.

⚠️ *No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression*

⚠️ *'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

`unlockForConfiguration` is not a throwing function. You don't need to `do { try ... } catch { ... }` around it.